# Remove all selected nodes in dynatree

Tags: javascript, dynatree

I want to remove all selected nodes from dynatree? But it throws an error if you delete a folder before the child. How can i delete the list of selected nodes in order of leaf nodes first?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < selectedNodes.length; i++) {
   selectedNodes[i].remove(); //Remove
 }
```